# How to consolidate duplicate blocks for Azure Role Assignments using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm currently working on managing role assignments in Terraform for Azure Storage Access, and I'm looking to streamline my code. Below is the snippet I'm working with,

```
locals {
  sa_we = "0c975d82-85a2-4b3a-bb23-9be5c681b66f"
  sa_gl = "9ee248b1-26f6-4d72-a3ac-7b77cf6c17f2"
}
    
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_account_access" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.jd-messenger.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader"
  principal_id         =  local.sa_we
}
    
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_account_access" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.jd-messenger.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader"
  principal_id         =  local.sa_gl
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to handle these role assignments. Specifically, I'm interested in consolidating these duplicate resource blocks into a single block, eliminating redundancy while still specifying different principal_id values.

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest recreating the local variable as a map:

```
locals {
  storage_accounts = {
    sa_we = "0c975d82-85a2-4b3a-bb23-9be5c681b66f"
    sa_gl = "9ee248b1-26f6-4d72-a3ac-7b77cf6c17f2"
  }
}
```

Then, using the [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta-argument you could use the resource block only once:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_account_access" {
  for_each             = local.storage_accounts
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.jd-messenger.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader for ${each.key}"
  principal_id         = each.value
}
```